# Calculated Field to index a String

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

How do I get the substring ABC from following string Hello(ABC). I used right and left function with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In english version of SharePoint it can be done with this:

```
=MID("Hello(ABC)", 7, 3)
```

There is a nice article:
http://yalla.itgroove.net/2012/09/sharepoint-calculated-column-formulas/

A dynamic version would be

```
 =MID("Hello(ABC)", SEARCH("(","Hello(ABC)")+1, SEARCH(")","Hello(ABC)")-SEARCH("(","Hello(ABC)")-1)
```

Comment: The parent String varies, It is not fixed hello(abc).. I wanted a calculated column that identifies "(" and ")" and returns string between it

Comment: So calculate indexes dynamically: =MID("Hello(ABC)", SEARCH("(","Hello(ABC)")+1, SEARCH(")","Hello(ABC)")-SEARCH("(","Hello(ABC)")-1)